# Crystal Decision Registration Wizard

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-8.5

I have Upgrade my report file Crystal Report 8.5 to ver.-9.00. Report files are intragated with vb6(No external   .rpt file). From many reports i upgrade 18 report file. When i run the project 18 times reminder me For "Crystal Decision Registration Wizard".Till i don not close project Every thing OK. If i close the project and reopen then again 18 times reminder me For "Crystal Decision Registration Wizard".

Answer (score 1):

I have Upgrade my report file Crystal Report 8.5 to ver.-9.00. Report files are intragated with vb6(No external .rpt file). From many reports i upgrade 30 report file. When i run the project 30 times reminder me For "Crystal Decision Registration Wizard".Till i don not close project Every thing OK. If i close the project and reopen then again 18 times reminder me For "Crystal Decision Registration Wizard".

Answer (score -1):

Simple,
first create an `exe` file with **Visual Basic**, write form load event just end

```
private sub form_load()
end
end sub
```

yes..your `exe` just start and end. Then compile it and rename it `regwiz.exe`
then, search `regwiz.exe` in your **local drive C** (before search, change the `directory setting->view, show hidden files and folder...` because sometimes if any file located in a directory which is hidden, windows can not find it).

Then replace your new `regwiz.exe` with the old one.

Crystal already will open 18 times but it will not wait your attention :) do not delete... I tried it will create